# How to share an `AsyncAPI` documentation with others?

Tags: api, asyncapi

Is there any way to share an **AsyncAPI** documentation with others? I used [AsyncAPI Studio](https://studio.asyncapi.com/) to write my API documentation. But I couldn't found  a share option in AsyncAPI studio. Is there a way in AsyncAPI Studio/any other AsyncAPI editors that we can used to share our API documentation with others?

In [SwaggerHub](https://support.smartbear.com/swaggerhub/docs/collaboration/sharing-api.html) we can share our rest api documentation with others which was written using OpenAPI specifications.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you have the possibility but limited. Studio doesn't save your specs in the cloud (there is no server for that), but if your spec is shared somewhere via http then you can use the `url` parameter with the `readOnly` parameter - the latter determines whether studio should render the spec with or without an editor.

It is also possible to use the `base64` parameter, but only for small specifications due to the limited length of links.

Example:

- with `url` parameter: https://studio.asyncapi.com/?url=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/asyncapi/spec/master/examples/gitter-streaming.yml&readOnly
- with `base64` parameter: https://studio.asyncapi.com/?base64=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&readOnly